# At boot time how OS determines all the hardware?

Tags: operating-system, hardware, enumeration, boot, bios

I have these related questions:

1. Does anybody know how an OS gets to know all hardware connected on the motherboard? (I guess this is called "Hardware Enumeration").
2. How does it determine what kind of hardware is residing at an specific IO address (i.e.: serial or parallel or whatever controller)?
3. How to code a system module which will do this job? (Assuming no OS loaded yet, just BIOS).

I know BIOS is just a validation and an user friendly interface to configure hardware at boot time with no real use after that for most modern OS's (win, Linux, etc). Besides I know that for the BIOS it should not be difficult to find all hardware because it is specifically tuned by the board manufacturer (who knows everything about it!). But for an OS or an application above BIOS that is a complete different story. Right?

Answer (score 5):

Pre-PCI this was much more difficult, you needed a trick for each product, and even with that it was difficult to figure everything out.  With usb and pci you can scan the busses to find a vendor and product id, from that you go into a product specific discovery (like the old days this can be difficult).  Sometimes the details for that board are protected by NDA or worse you just dont get to know unless you work there on the right team.

The general approach is either based on detection (usb, pcie, etc vendor/product ids) you load a driver or write a driver for that family of product based on the documentation for that family of product.  Since you mentioned BIOS, win, linux that implies X86 or a PC, and that pretty much covers the autodetectable.  Beyond that you rely on the user who knows what hardware was installed in the system and a driver that came with it.  or in some way you ask them what is installed (the specific printer at the end of a cable or out on the network if not auto detectable is an easy to understand example).

In short you take decades of experience in trying to succeed at this and apply it, and still fail from time to time since you are not in 100% control of all the hardware in the system, there are hundreds of vendors out there each doing their own thing.

BIOS enumerates the pci(e) for an x86 pc, for other platforms the OS might do it.  The enumeration includes allocating address space for the device based on pci compliant rules.  but within that address space you have to know how to program that specific board from vendor documentation if available.

Comment: how does the bios enumerate pcie?  someone read the pci spec and the docs for the pcie hardware and processor and just implemented the spec.  same goes for usb, read the spec, read the docs for the hardware.

Comment: First, thanx for telling the path to follow (PCI & USB specs). So basically, in a x86 system all you have to do is ask the PCI and USB hardware for the rest of the devices attached to them. But now, how did you find these 2 buddies in the first place? Please, forgive my newbe ignorance in these matters. By the way, I was wondering how is it done in a non-PCI & USB boards (Beagle, Raspberry, etc). Or do they adhere to the PCI & USB bus standard too?

Comment: raspberry pi has usb, not sure about beagles.  to some extent those platforms fall into the just tell me what you have category.  porting linux to those platforms involves compiling in the module for the specific video, etc.

Comment: the pcie and usb, the bios for a motherboard is extremely specific to that exact motherboard, you compile in code for the exact hardware on that motherboard as far as pcie masters and bridges and such, and the usb host hardware so that the keyboard and maybe mouse works in the bios or to hit a key to enter setup, etc.

Comment: dwelch, Thanx a lot! I see very dark areas around this hardware acknowlegment process at boot time. I thought there was  some kind of 'standard way of doing this thing' which worked good for many types of hardware platforms. But what a disapointment!!!

Comment: well in some respects there is.  you build a motherboard (not a trivial task) and you pay ami bios to make your bios, then the computer just boots like any other...

Comment: in the case of embedded, ARM for example makes cores not chips, the chip vendors dont have to get along and in some (many?) cases patents and other lawsuits might prevent them from getting along, so they do their own thing.  But here again you make your chip and then board and hire some one to port linux for a few weeks, done.

Comment: I think in general the industry prevents the notion of getting along and conforming to a standard, even when there is a standard (pci, html, postscript, etc) they try to make their own non-compatible variant to make software not work well with others...

Answer (score 4):

Sorry my English is not very good.

Responding questions 1 and 2:

During the boot process, only the hardware modules strictly necessary to find and start the OS are loaded.

These hardware modules are: motherboard, hard drive, RAM, graphics card, keyboard, mouse, screen (that is detected by the graphics card), network card, CD / DVD, and a few extra peripherals such as USB units.

Each hardware module you connect to a computer has a controller that is like a small BIOS with all the information of the stored device: manufacturer, device type, protocols, etc

The detection process is very simple: the BIOS has hardcoded all the information about the motherboard, with all communication ports. At startup, the BIOS sends a signal to all system ports asking the questions "Who are you? What are you? How do you function?" and all attached devices answers by sending their information. In this way the computer knows how much RAM you have, if there is present a keyboard or a mouse, which storage devices are available, screen resolution, etc ...

Obviously, this process only works with the basic modules needed to boot the system, and does not work with complex peripherals that require specific drivers: printers, scanners, webcams ... all these complex peripherals are loaded by software once the OS has been charged.

Responding question 3:

If you wants to load a specific module during the boot, you must:
- Create a controller for this module.
- If the peripheral is too complex to load everything from the controller, you must to write all the proccess to control that module directly in the BIOS module, or reprogram the IPL to manage that specific module.

I hope I've helped

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when you turn on your system, the BIOS starts the IPL (Initial program load) from ROM. For check the all connected devices are working good and also check the mandatory devices such as keyboard, CMOS, Hard disk and so on. If it is not success, it gives an error flag to the BIOS. The BIOS shows us the error through video devices.

If it is success, the control of boot is transferred to BIOS for further process.

The above all process are called POST (Power On Self Test).

Now the BIOS have the control. It checks all secondary memory devices for boot loader of the OS. If it hit, the bootloader's memory address is transferred to RAM.

The Ram started to execute the bootloader. Here only the os starts to run.

If the bootloader not hit, the bios shows us the boot failure error.

I hope your doubt clarified...

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me. It is precisely when you say 'For checking all connected devices are working ..'. That is the real thing I am willing to know how is it done. I have read on some literature that when the OS is loading it is verifying and configuring all detected hardware. Again that is the point where I need some light about how it is done. Anyway thanx a lot.